# Dynamic inserting HTML inside DIV and accessing the new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading remote HTML into a DIV using jQuery and need to access all the elements and JS contained therein. Seems as though the inserted HTML is added and renders correctly but the elements are not in the DOM. How can I access these new elements ? Using document.getElementById('myDiv') returns null

var canvas .. in the script below returns null and I don't understand why.

```
<script>

function draw(){
  var canvas=document.getElementById("pdf1");
  var pdf=canvas.getContext("2d");
// other code here populates canvas.....

}

</script>

<body>
<div>
<canvas  id="pdf1" width="801" height="1041"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
<script type="application/javascript">
$(window).load(draw());
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you adding remote html? code snippet please...

Comment: if they was rendered, they are accesible. Please edit your question and add to it the code to check what happened

Comment: we need to see what you're adding to the document and HOW you're adding it.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, use the .find() - which searches through all the sub elements at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#new_html_wrapper').load('file.html', function(){

    // Access the new DOM elements here inside the load callback.

    $(this).on('#myDiv','click',function(){
        alert('You clicked on myDiv!');
    });

    $('#myDiv', this).css('background','red');

});

// Accessing the elements here will fail as they haven't been loaded yet.
```

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Also don't use `document.getElementById('myDiv')`.

You already have jQuery loaded so do: `$('#myDiv')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to bind events to those new elements use the [.on() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

You would have tried to get the content before HTML inserted there.
you should try accessing the element after content inserted. i.e. if you call the same function after content inserted, you can get the content in div.

or if you want to bind some events like click, on the content which comes later(inserted data like in your case) as well, you can live bind the events as below

$("div.className").live("click",function(){ alert('1'); })
 or  
$("document").on("div.className","click",function(){ alert('1'); })

Comment: Just say no to `.live()`; its depreciated.